# Is mirrordirector.raspbian.org IPv6 down?

Tags: raspbian, networking

Everytime I do apt-get something this host takes a minute to timeout, altough all the others are fine in IPv6.

The host is mirrordirector.raspbian.org (2001:41c9:1:3ce::11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mirrordirector.raspbian.org` is occasionally down, even on IPv4, due to regular maintenance or some other reason.

As of now, it's up.

If your connection is failing right now, I would advise you to check your network equipment or if your ISP/network equipment supports IPv6. You can also check [here](http://test-ipv6.com/).